# Rails IPv6 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ipv6

I'm using a development server which I currently only have IPv6 connectivity to, and I'm working on a rails application.

I tried to use `bundle exec rails s -e development -p 3003 -d` to start a server, but it seems it only binds to IPv4:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3003                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27165/ruby
```

thus I can't connect to it. What's my best option to proceed? I'm not really very familiar with rails just trying to fix a few issues on an existing application.

version info:

```
:; ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
:; rails --version
Rails 3.2.8
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I can't find any documentation that the default Webrick server in rails does IPv6. From what I understand you'd have to use nginx or something similar that supports it.

Comment: Figured it out myself, `-b ::` will make it listen on both. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can accept your own answers..just add it and accept..

Comment: @Casper alright, I'll do that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out myself, `-b ::` will make it listen on both IPv6 and IPv4 (depending on sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only probably).

Answer (score 5):

On puma you should do:

```
rails s -b [::]
```

as per [RFC2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt), literal IPv6 addresses should be put inside squares. If not, you will receive a parsing error.