# Can't connect to docker after resuming VM

Tags: docker

For some reason whenever I suspend my VM and resume it, I can no longer connect to the docker container that is hosted within the VM. Usually, I pass `-p 3000:3000` to the docker container so that I can access the rails instance within it and this works fine, but when I suspend the VM and resume it later, I can no longer connect to port 3000 even though it's listening within the docker image.

This results in me having to reboot the VM as `service docker restart` does not change anything.

Is there something else I should be looking at to resolve this issue? I've been suspending/resuming my VM with docker in it for quite awhile and have never run into this issue before.

**EDIT**

To reproduce this issue, I simply resumed my VM and tried connecting to localhost port 3000 from the VM itself (not within the docker image) and it cannot connect. However, below shows that port 3000 is listening:

```
[root:kali:~/app]# curl http://localhost:3000
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root:kali:~/app]# netstat -antp | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43050         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      84770/autossh       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20478/sshd          
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      32731/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      32715/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      20478/sshd
```

From within docker, I can see that rails is working:

```
[root:77f444beafff:~/app]# rails s --binding 0.0.0.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

And here's the netstat from within docker:

```
[root:77f444beafff:~/app]# netstat -antp | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      478/redis-server *: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      765/puma 3.12.1 (tc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::6379
```

If I curl from within the docker image, I can see it hits the rails app just fine:

```
[root:77f444beafff:~/app]# curl http://localhost:3000/ -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"5078d30a6c1a5f6fc5cb7f9a82cd89f5"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _vspm_session=Cace%2FN0zB%2F6QJOiietbuHxTHOMZUMuRmEukYqQTNaHQ91hskaN%2BPJzev0KdGUAAtYx9a35Mqdkr8eRkPdH4qOl6vOaCcPU0gy8s7IMfkb9VhRGPPbecepmI%2F9leA2dnD694P8ctXSBklOCnjhN0%3D--SglWrWvx3BFEAI3z--IkylACdXbR6eF27Hgn0Cgg%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 29aa7251-f29a-4309-adec-6af479e7bd9b
X-Runtime: 12.241723
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm having exactly the same issue with my VMWare virtual machine (VMWare running on Windows).

The only workaround that is working for me is:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager docker
```

If I had to guess I would say it may be related to some firewall rules docker setup on start, maybe when you resume the virtual machine a change in the network configuration breaks those rules.

Similar issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1990 (Doesn't seem specific to docker for mac).

Comment: Works for me, Ubuntu 20.20 virtualized from W10 host with VMWare Workstation.

Comment: This gives additional background: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7405, at the end of the issue you can find a link to this gist: https://gist.github.com/lanrat/458066dbdeb460b9cef40dc2af639a24, which discusses ways to configure NetworkManager to ignore the docker interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this issue with the hint given by [lannox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474034/lanoxx) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874055/cant-connect-to-docker-after-resuming-vm#comment125703053_62939675). It's necessary to mark the network interfaces of the docker containers as *unmanaged* by NetworkManager.

To do that, create a new file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-unmanage-docker-interfaces.conf` with the following content:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker*;interface-name:veth*;interface-name:br-*;interface-name:vmnet*;interface-name:vboxnet*
```

This configures NetworkManager to ignore all interfaces with names `docker*`,
`veth*`,
`br-*`,
`vmnet*`, and
`vboxnet*` interfaces.

Then restart NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Next time the host suspends and resumes, the docker containers keep their network connectivity.

Comment: This answer was immensely helpful to our organization! I work for a group that creates IT/CyberSecurity training classes. We provide a multitude of VMs to our students. Many of these run docker images for ELK/OpenSearch and tools built on this and similar platforms. This fix is super simple while being effective. THANK. YOU. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Several questions here that might help you solve this :

- Is your docker container still running? Run `docker ps` and find your container
- Since the `-p 3000:3000` option is set I guess the port is exposed, but you might want to check you really have run your container with this option this time
- Is your app really listening? Run `lsof -np | grep listen` and find your app listening on port 3000
- Connect to your container with `docker exec -it <your_container> bash` and try running `lsof -np | grep listen` to see if this is a docker issue or your app

Comment: Docker container is still running (I am in a tmux session managing the application). I've also tried to shut down the rails server and re-start it. I can also confirm it's listening with `curl http://localhost:3000` and see it within the docker container.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you with the informations I have. Can you update the question with steps to reproduce?

Comment: Just updated the question to contain some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you run `netstat` on your VM you get the following line :

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      32731/docker-proxy
```

On Docker you get :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      765/puma 3.12.1 (tc
```

There are two differences here:

- `:::3000` vs `0 0.0.0.0:3000`, the first means it is listening on IPv6 and the second on IPv4 (found the info [on this question](https://superuser.com/questions/661188/what-is-in-the-local-address-of-netstat-output?newreg=c2a35cb67e354c12a33b995cbbc569cc)).
- `tcp6` vs `tcp`, again IPv6 vs IPv4.

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725236/rails-ipv6-server), it seems you have to run rails with `-b ::` option.

> The -b option binds Rails to the specified IP, by default it is localhost. You can run a server as a daemon by passing a -d option.

Comment: Not sure why it only occurs after you resume the VM though. You may want to run `netstat` before you resume just to see if it is also IPv6 vs IPv4.

Comment: Yeah it's very strange. I just restarted docker service and apparently it's working again. However, my netstat outputs look exactly the same. I think this may just have something to do with the way it's passed from the docker container or something. Very strange.

Comment: Might be worth making a ticket on the docker github with a dummy rails app to reproduce.

Comment: Absolutely. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please do

```
sudo docker ps
```

If you do not got your container do

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

Does your container is stopped?
If its true so do

```
sudo docker start CONTAINER_ID
```

Comment: That's the thing -- my container isn't stopped because I have it opened and actively running commands in it.

Comment: try to stop

`sudo docker stop CONTAINER_ID`

and run it again

`sudo docker start CONTAINER_ID`